# Copied workbook with macro to another computer and does not work on recieving computer

Tags: excel, vba

As the question say I made a simple macro that takes a couple sheets of data and turns it into charts. The marco works perfectly on my laptop however, when I email my boss the workbook containing the macro it does not work. If i remember correctly it threw error 42 or something.

The line in my code it highlighted was the line that set the title of the graph. I feed a function that creates my graphs titles from an array that gets looped through via For loop. Once i changed it to a different text value and took out the array it worked.

Button that controls macro

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim selectedWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim numItems As Integer
Dim numOfIdentifiers As Integer
Dim identArray() As String
Dim itemsFoundL() As String
Dim itemsSoldL() As Integer
Dim identifiers As Range
Dim ident As Range
Dim upperBound As String
Dim lowerBound As String
Dim foodLBound As String
Dim foodUBound As String
Dim nonFoodLBound As String
Dim nonFoodUBound As String
Dim foodNameColumn As String
Dim foodSoldColumn As String
Dim nonFoodNameColumn As String
Dim nonFoodSoldColumn As String

Dim sheetName As Range
Dim i As Integer

upperBound = Range("J1").Value
lowerBound = Range("I1").Value

foodLBound = Range("I3").Value
foodUBound = Range("J3").Value

nonFoodLBound = Range("I4").Value
nonFoodUBound = Range("J4").Value

foodNameColumn = Range("I5").Value
foodSoldColumn = Range("I6").Value

nonFoodNameColumn = Range("I8").Value
nonFoodSoldColumn = Range("I9").Value

Set sheetName = Range("I2")
Set identifiers = Range(lowerBound, upperBound)
Set selectedWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(CStr(sheetName))


numOfIdentifiers = identifiers.Count
ReDim identArray(0 To numOfIdentifiers - 1)


i = 0
For Each ident In identifiers

identArray(i) = ident.Value
i = i + 1
Next ident

For i = 0 To numOfIdentifiers - 1

numItems = CInt(numberOfItems(selectedWorksheet, identArray(i),  foodLBound, foodUBound))
If numItems = 0 Then

numItems = CInt(numberOfItems(selectedWorksheet, identArray(i),    nonFoodLBound, nonFoodUBound))
numItems = numItems - 1
ReDim itemsFoundL(0 To numItems)
ReDim itemsSoldL(0 To numItems)

itemsFoundL = itemsFound(selectedWorksheet, identArray(i), nonFoodLBound,    nonFoodUBound, numItems, nonFoodNameColumn)
itemsSoldL = itemsSoldFound(selectedWorksheet, identArray(i), nonFoodLBound, nonFoodUBound, numItems, nonFoodSoldColumn)


Else

numItems = numItems - 1
ReDim itemsFoundL(0 To numItems)
ReDim itemsSoldL(0 To numItems)

 itemsFoundL = itemsFound(selectedWorksheet, identArray(i), foodLBound,    foodUBound, numItems, foodNameColumn)
 itemsSoldL = itemsSoldFound(selectedWorksheet, identArray(i), foodLBound, foodUBound, numItems, foodSoldColumn)

 End If

 Call CreateCharts(itemsFoundL, itemsSoldL, identArray(i), numItems)

Next i

End Sub
```

Chart creating helper function

```
 Function CreateCharts(items As Variant, itemsSold As Variant, chartTitle As String, itemCount As Integer)

 If itemCount > 0 Then

Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarStacked
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = items
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = itemsSold
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
With ActiveChart

.HasLegend = False
.HasTitle = True
.chartTitle.Text = chartTitle

End With


Else
End If

End Function
```

Comment: The exact error number, as well as the line that throws the error, would be helpful to debug this.

Comment: The line that throws the error is `.chartTitle.Text = chartTitle` in the createCharts function

Comment: And what's the specific value in the array when adding the title fails?